Jetpack Compose - Weird Line in ExposedDropdownMenuBox
I have an Android Native Jetpack Compose application that I have written. I am trying to use a background image in my application. For the most part, everything looks good.
However, when I run my app on my Samsung Galaxy, I am seeing a weird light line that doesn’t occur when I’m running in IntelliJ with the device emulator. I have an ExposedDropdownMenuBox that contains a Card, which contains a Box with a Row with a Text element (the code and images follow below).
I’ve been trying to figure out which element is showing the line but can’t seem to find where it is occurring. I’m hoping someone more familiar with JetPack Compose and Material can tell me what I need to change to get rid of the line.
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = chooseFactionsExpanded,
            onExpandedChange = {
                chooseFactionsExpanded = !chooseFactionsExpanded
            },
        ) {

            var paddingModifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
            Card(
                elevation = 10.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                modifier = paddingModifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(0.dp)
                    .border(BorderStroke(0.dp, homeScreenStyles.backgroundColor))
                ,
                backgroundColor = homeScreenStyles.backgroundColor,
                border = BorderStroke(0.dp, homeScreenStyles.backgroundColor),
            ) {

                Box {
                    Row {
                        Text(
                            getAppText(MODULE_NAME, "chooseFactions"),
                            fontSize = homeScreenStyles.chooseItemsFontSize,
                        )
                        Spacer(Modifier.weight(10f))
                        Icon(
                            if (chooseFactionsExpanded)
                                Icons.Rounded.KeyboardArrowDown
                            else
                                Icons.Rounded.KeyboardArrowRight,
                            contentDescription = null,
                        )
                    }
                }
…

Here is the emulator screenshot without the light lines:

Here is the screenshot from my Samsung Galaxy with the annoying lines:

Any ideas how to get rid of those lines?
